# Kendo Grid Complex Row UI

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to develop a kendo grid with multiple rows within a parent row(child rows inside parent rows). Can I achieve this using kendo grid. I didn't see much example on the web if someone can guide me to a good resource that would be great

Thanks

Chinthaka

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the sample [Hierarchy](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html) page on the Kendo site? It shows how to have sub-grids.

There's also the [Detail Template](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/detailtemplate.html) sample, which shows how to have a tabbed child with a grid and a "more info" kind of tab.

Comment: Hi Walter thanks for your response. Actually I went through that but My requirement is to display multiple rows inside single row without colums also without collapse

Comment: In that case, look at the Row Template sample: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/rowtemplate.html

Comment: I'll give it a try n let you know That still a single level ryte ??